# Expect script procedure seems to be quitting and the rest of the script is not quite following execution

Tags: function, ssh, expect, procedure

So I used to have a script that would log into a switch and interact, or run a bunch of commands and quit. 
Well, i tried to make it more secure by incorporating a function from another file, and now things are just not working.
It seems that when the function is done, the ssh session quits, interact in function or outside is not working, and certainly following up with more commands is not going well....

I would appreciate some ideas on what is wrong:

1st script containing the function [ ssssh2 ]:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect   

proc log-in { host } {
 set timeout 20
 set passfile [open "~/bin/.l" r]
 gets $passfile pass
 gets $passfile enab
 gets $passfile user
 close $passfile

 spawn ssh $user@$host

 expect -timeout 5 {
  "yes/no" { send "yes\r" }
  "#" {}
  }
 expect "word"
 send "$pass\r" 
 expect { 
  "#" {}
  ">" {
  send "en\r"
  expect "word"
  send "$enab\r" 
  }
 }
 send "\r"
 expect "#"
 send "terminal length 0\r"
 expect "#"
}
```

Here's the script that calls it - at this point i want interact at the end, in other variations it might be an ongoing string of switch commands ending with logout. This script runs with -d for debug [sssh2 ]

```
#!/usr/bin/expect  -d 
source ~/bin/ssssh2

log-in $argv 

send "\r"
expect "#"
send "terminal length 50\r"
expect "#"

interact
```

And here's the output in debug mode:

```
# sssh2 host***
expect version 5.45
argv[0] = /usr/bin/expect  argv[1] = -d  argv[2] = /root/bin/sssh2  argv[3] = host***  
set argc 1
set argv0 "/root/bin/sssh2"
set argv "host***"
executing commands from command file /root/bin/sssh2
spawn ssh user***@host***
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {3729}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "\n  "yes/no" { send "yes\r" }\n  "#" {}\n  "? no
host*** Radius Enabled

expect: does "host*** Radius Enabled\r\r\n" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "\n  "yes/no" { send "yes\r" }\n  "#" {}\n  "? no
user***@host***'s password: 
expect: does "host*** Radius Enabled\r\r\nuser***@host***'s password: " (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "\n  "yes/no" { send "yes\r" }\n  "#" {}\n  "? no
expect: timed out

expect: does "host*** Radius Enabled\r\r\nuser***@host***'s password: " (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "word"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "word"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp7"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "host*** Radius Enabled\r\r\nuser***@host***'s password"
send: sending "mypass***\r" to { exp7 }

expect: does ": " (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "#"? no
">"? no


expect: does ": \r\n" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "#"? no
">"? no

host***>
expect: does ": \r\n\r\nhost***>" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "#"? no
">"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) ">"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp7"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) ": \r\n\r\nhost***>"
send: sending "en\r" to { exp7 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "word"? no
e
expect: does "e" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "word"? no
n
Password:
expect: does "en\r\nPassword:" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "word"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "word"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp7"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "en\r\nPassword"
send: sending "mypass2***\r" to { exp7 }
send: sending "\r" to { exp7 }

expect: does ":" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "#"? no
*
expect: does ":*" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "#"? no
*****************

host***#
host***#
expect: does ":******************\r\n\r\nhost***#\r\nhost***#" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "#"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "#"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp7"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) ":******************\r\n\r\nhost***#"
send: sending "terminal length 0\r" to { exp7 }

expect: does "\r\nhost***#" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "#"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "#"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp7"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\r\nhost***#"
}end: sending "\r" to { exp0 

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp0) match glob pattern "#"? no
expect: timed out
}end: sending "terminal length 50\r" to { exp0 terminal length 50

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp0) match glob pattern "#"? no
expect: timed out
cannot interact with self - set spawn_id to a spawned process
    while executing
"interact"
    (file "/root/bin/sssh2" line 11)
```

I am at a loss here..... Thx for any help!

GT

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Answer (score 1):

Add this at the beginning of the `log-in` proc:

```
proc log-in { host } {
  global spawn_id timeout

  ...
```

According to Expect's [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/expect.1.html):

> Expect takes a rather liberal view of scoping.  In particular, variables read  by  commands  specific  to  the Expect program will be sought first from the local scope, and if not found, in the global scope.  For example, this obviates the need to place `global timeout` in every procedure you write that uses expect.  On the  other hand,  **variables  written are always in the local scope (unless a `global` command has been issued)**.  The most common problem this causes is when `spawn` is executed in a  procedure.   Outside  the  procedure,  `spawn_id`  no longer  exists,  so  the  spawned  process  is  no longer accessible simply because of scoping.  Add a `global spawn_id` to such a procedure.

Comment: Looks like that was it! Thx! I started suspecting scope, but could not find details on scope for spawn! very cool!!!

Comment: @GregT please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers -- accept this answer since it solved your problem.